# Do jhipster support repository other than git or sourcetree?

Tags: jhipster

I want to create an application without using jhipster but don't want to use GitHub. Is it possible?. I am getting the below error while creating a application .

```
C:\Users\user\myApplication>yo jhipster
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'downgrade-root'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\root-check\index.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, your title seems to be a question about a feature and then you speak about an error

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is just an online project hosting using Git, and a JHipster application is just a huge Spring Boot application that you can host in BitBucket, GitLab, SVN, a zip file, etc.

The error you are having is just something else... It looks like an 'npm' error, but you are not giving enough context so we can help you.